# launching fancybox gallery via a function?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

In short im trying to launch fancybox with a gallery but via an iframe and a manual call to launch fancybox.

Im currently launching fancybox via a function and using iframe mode successfully (without a gallery).  This allows me to give the popup lightbox much more specific formatting control and also because by using a function i can parse data to the function from the item in the main page launching the lightbox which is then again parsed onto the iframe via the function (see example function below).

The problem is that I dont know how to make lightbox realise that im trying to define a group of images that it will interpret as a gallery by using this method.

So can i somehow launch an inframe in a function whilst starting a gallery ?

```
function testFunction(caption){
    $.fancybox({
        "overlayOpacity":0.8,
        "type" : "iframe",
        "width" : "100%",
        "height" : "100%",
        "padding": 0,
        "margin": 0,
        "content": "test.php?cap="+caption
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an array of image objects, in this format:

```
var images = [];
images.push({'href': 'http://www.mydomain.com/example.gif', title:'myName'});

$.fancybox.open(images, { 
    // all the other parameters here
});
```

You need to use [version 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) if I am correct

Comment: Hi Topener. Thanks for the help.  That works for inline but as soon as I add the parameter "type" : "iframe",   it stops working, with the pushed image loading directly in the url, taking the user away from the html page we were in.

Comment: ahhh damm.  im not using that and i wont be able to upgrade to the new version either for the project im on as its breaking too many other areas.

Comment: ah too bad. But what exactly are you trying to achieve? If it works in version 1 then it should work too. But if not for iFrame, what do you want to do with the iFrames? Multiple iFrames?